# Should I convert C static function to private member function or free function in unnamed namespace?

Tags: c++, c, static, upgrade, unnamed-namespace

I want to update some C legacy code to C++. Suppose I had something similar to this code in C:

```cpp
//my_struct.h
typedef struct myStruct {
//some members go here
} myStruct;

int f1(myStruct*);
void f2(myStruct*);
```

```cpp
//my_struct.c
#include "my_struct.h"

static int helper(myStruct* st)
{
   return 21;
}

int f1(myStruct* st)
{
   return helper(st);
}

void f2(myStruct* st) {}
```

If I update it to the following in CPP:

```cpp
//myStruct.h
struct myStruct {
   int f1();
   void f2();
private:
   int helper();
};
```

```cpp
//myStruct.cpp
int myStruct::f1(){
   return helper();
}

void myStruct::f2(){}

int myStruct::helper(){
   return 21;
}
```

What is the impact of converting the global static C function to a private member function in C++?

What would be the pros/cons (regarding compilation, linking, runtime) between the previous approach and the following one? I didn't use the parameter inside the function to make the example short (If it is not used I read in other questions that it should probably go to the anonymous namespace).

```cpp
//myStruct.h
struct myStruct {
   int f1();
   void f2();
}
```

```cpp
//myStruct.cpp
namespace{
   int helper(myStruct *st){
      return 21;
   }
}
int myStruct::f1(){
   return helper(this);
}

void myStruct::f2(){}
```

Comment: IMO the first option is the best.

Comment: You’re exposing the function to the outside world. Compilation time will probably increase slightly due to richer interface and compiler will have to emit a symbol due to external linkage. The rest is subject to build settings, e.g. LTO; my guess is that members are less likely to be inlined, but I might be wrong here.

Comment: If `helper` doesn't really need `this` then second option, otherwise—first.

Comment: Static functions is also a thing in C++. Anonymous namespaces were used to enable things to be used with templates, at a time when all template parameters had to have external linkage. That requirement was relaxed a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the impact of converting the global static C function to a private member function in C++?

The impact is that you've made a (private, internal) implementation detail of your module part of the (public) interface.

> What would be the pros/cons (regarding compilation, linking, runtime) between the previous approach and the following one?

Cons:

- you've added semantic noise to your interface

  ie, there's more for clients to read and think about, even though it shouldn't affect them,
- changes to internal implementation details *may* require all clients of the interface to recompile, instead of just re-linking

  ie, if you want to change `helper`, that now updates the public header and causes widespread recompilation of files that shouldn't be affected

Pros:

- there are none.

It's idiomatic in C++ to add implementation-file-local details like `helper` to the anonymous namespace.

Comment: Or static function in a cpp file.

Comment: So the only good reason to have helper as a private member function is if needs to access private data that doesn't have getter methods?

Comment: Yes, in general. You may also want to use private methods when everything is inline (such as for templates), because there _is_ no implementation file to put them in.